# Upload file to blob storage error get_NetworkTimeout does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, azure, .net-4.6.1

I tried to to call `TransferManager.UploadAsync` but I keep getting this error:

```
Method 'get_NetworkTimeout' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.FileRequestOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File, Version=11.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
```

This is my method in `BaseBlobRepository.cs`:

```
public void Add(string name, System.IO.Stream fileStream, string contentType = null)
{
    TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
    SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext();
    context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>((progress) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
    });
    var container = GetBlobContainer(_containerName);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
    if (contentType != null)
    {
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
    }
    var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(
        fileStream, blockBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
    task.Wait();
}
```

Comment: maybe it's because you are passing `null` as [retryOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.retryoptions?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: It may get an old version of the dll from the GAC, hence the error. So add a reference to `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File` into your project and the error should be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this happened when I installed NuGet package `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common` v11.1.7 but forgot to install `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved in the latest release. Upgrade your Azure packages to 11.1.7
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues/223

Comment: Im getting this error even with the latest version!